# Installing iMember360 plugin To WordPress MU

Tags: php, wordpress, infusionsoft

I am installing iMember360 plugin for infusionsoft to my Wordpress Multi Site but after installation, it forced me to logoff and I am no more able to access my Wordpress admin panel using my credential.

I am able to login but it seems I am not getting admin privilege.At `/wp-admin/` It Says > You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

I Tried Deactivating all the plugin then again installed iMember360 **Still facing the same problem**

Any idea.. ?

[image: Screenshot after Plugin Activation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot network activate the plugin. You have to activate it on the individual sites. Try this and see if it makes a difference. I have iMember360 installed on several MU sites with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here and see if this fixes your issue:
http://ericwijaya.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page-after-database-prefix-change/

Comment: From article it seems I have some of the database problem, Thank You @joshmmo I'll see if this will fix my problem.

Comment: Hi @joshmmo I tried to fix database prefix but was no luck., 

Any other suggestion.. ?